# Python - how do you embed matplotlib animation in a Qwidget created in Qt designer?

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation, qt-designer

Starting of with embedding matplotlib into a Qwidget I followed the following tutorial:
https://yapayzekalabs.blogspot.com/2018/11/pyqt5-gui-qt-designer-matplotlib.html

Files can be downloaded here:
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/10V1Nh1xAVAfwydBtsJvoVGaYiR_HI15X?usp=sharing

The tutorial includes a mplwidget.py file:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.figure import Figure


class MplWidget(QWidget):

def __init__(self, parent=None):
    QWidget.__init__(self, parent)

    self.canvas = FigureCanvas(Figure())

    vertical_layout = QVBoxLayout()
    vertical_layout.addWidget(self.canvas)

    self.canvas.axes = self.canvas.figure.add_subplot(111)
    self.setLayout(vertical_layout)
```

main.py:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import*
from PyQt5.uic import loadUi
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import (NavigationToolbar2QT as NavigationToolbar)
import numpy as np
import random

class MatplotlibWidget(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):

        QMainWindow.__init__(self)

        loadUi("qt_designer.ui",self)

        self.setWindowTitle("PyQt5 & Matplotlib Example GUI")

        self.pushButton_generate_random_signal.clicked.connect(self.update_graph)

        self.addToolBar(NavigationToolbar(self.MplWidget.canvas, self))


    def update_graph(self):

        fs = 500
        f = random.randint(1, 100)
        ts = 1/fs
        length_of_signal = 100
        t = np.linspace(0,1,length_of_signal)

        cosinus_signal = np.cos(2*np.pi*f*t)
        sinus_signal = np.sin(2*np.pi*f*t)

        self.MplWidget.canvas.axes.clear()
        self.MplWidget.canvas.axes.plot(t, cosinus_signal)
        self.MplWidget.canvas.axes.plot(t, sinus_signal)
        self.MplWidget.canvas.axes.legend(('cosinus', 'sinus'),loc='upper right')
        self.MplWidget.canvas.axes.set_title('Cosinus - Sinus Signal')
        self.MplWidget.canvas.draw()


app = QApplication([])
window = MatplotlibWidget()
window.show()
app.exec_()
```

and the qt_designer.ui file which has a button and a Qwidget (Promoted to MplWidget within QT Designer).

This works great for a static matplotlib graph, but can't seem to make an animation work. I think I don't understand what is seen as the `figure` in this case. What do I need to send to

`FuncAnimation(fig, func, frames=None, init_func=None, fargs=None, save_count=None, *, cache_frame_data=True, **kwargs)[source]`

to display the graph as an animation, of lets say 10 random graphs being displayed one after the other?

I have tried changing the code to something like this:

```
#In the init function
self.pushButton_generate_random_signal.clicked.connect(self.update_animation)

def update_animation(self):
    self.ani = animation.FuncAnimation(self.MplWidget.canvas, self.update_graph, interval=1000)
    self.MplWidget.canvas.draw()

def update_graph(self):
    for k in range(1, 10):
        fs = 500
        f = random.randint(1, 100)
        ts = 1/fs
        length_of_signal = 100
        t = np.linspace(0,1,length_of_signal)

        cosinus_signal = np.cos(2*np.pi*f*t)
        sinus_signal = np.sin(2*np.pi*f*t)

        self.MplWidget.canvas.axes.clear()
        self.MplWidget.canvas.axes.plot(t, cosinus_signal)
        self.MplWidget.canvas.axes.plot(t, sinus_signal)
```

But that breaks python completely. Most examples research uses matplotlib.pyplot as plt with `fig = plt.plot`. So I think I don't understand how to set the `MplWidget` as a plot. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: change `ani` to `self.ani`

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Make sense that it should be self and edited the post, but it still does not work.

Comment: provide a [mre]

Comment: Thanks eyllanesc. Got it to work and posted the answer, although it seems that it restarts the animation after it completes the 10 loops.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to eyllanesc in the comments I realised that ani should be self.ani and from there that I had to change self.MplWidget.canvas to just self.MplWidget. I also updated the structure and added the 'repeat = False' statement to stop the animation after 10 loops. The following main.py works:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.uic import loadUi

from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import (NavigationToolbar2QT as 
NavigationToolbar)
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import random

class MatplotlibWidget(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self): # Create matplotlib interface
        super(MatplotlibWidget, self).__init__()
        loadUi("qt_designer.ui", self)
        self.setWindowTitle("PyQt5 & Matplotlib Example GUI")
        self.addToolBar(NavigationToolbar(self.MplWidget.canvas, self))
        self.pushButton_generate_random_signal.clicked.connect(self.update_animation)

    def update_animation(self):
        self.ani = animation.FuncAnimation(self.MplWidget, self.update_axes, 
        self.update_graph, interval=1000, repeat=False)
        self.MplWidget.canvas.draw()

    def update_graph(self):
        for k in range(1, 10):
            fs = 500
            f = random.randint(1, 100)
            ts = 1 / fs
            length_of_signal = 100
            t = np.linspace(0, 1, length_of_signal)

            cosinus_signal = np.cos(2 * np.pi * f * t)
            sinus_signal = np.sin(2 * np.pi * f * t)
            yield t, cosinus_signal, sinus_signal


    def update_axes(self, update):
        t, cosinus_signal, sinus_signal = update[0], update[1], update[2]
        self.MplWidget.canvas.axes.clear()
        self.MplWidget.canvas.axes.plot(t, cosinus_signal)
        self.MplWidget.canvas.axes.plot(t, sinus_signal)


app = QApplication([])
window = MatplotlibWidget()
window.show()
app.exec_()
```